# Is there a website design program that can connect directly to SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, web

Hello I am a novice web designer and coder but I have an idea and want to complete this project.

I want to create a website that has html forms and when they are submitted they go to an sqlite database. I'm using Sqlite because after a user submits the information from the html form and gets sent to the database it will then be received by xcode and used in an iphone app.

All I'm focused on now is building a great looking website in a program that can connect to sqlite.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely sure of your question here, but based solely on your headline... "Yes."  With the correct connection string, virtually any programming language can be made to communicate with your SQLite Database.  Are you having some kind of problem with your language of choice?

Comment: With the way this question is worded, I'm afraid you're restricting yourself a bit too much. For what it sounds like you're building, you can use pretty much any database on your web server (not just SQLite) and then have your iPhone app retrieve from the database using XMLRPC or REST. Unrelated note, I find it humorous that your SO avatar was generated as burnt orange, given your username :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of these things rather easily with the Ruby on Rails framework.